# Simplest split tunneling solution (per application) for OpenVPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I use ExpressVPN, and on Android I have an app that will allow me to choose which apps run through the VPN. Everything else uses normal traffic. I can also install ExpressVPN on Ubuntu, but it doesn't have the split tunneling feature.

I set up OpenVPN to use my VPN, but when I turn it on, it routes all my traffic through it.  When I check 'Use this connection only for resources on this network', this seems to allow my LAN traffic to stay off the VPN.

However, I only really want one or two applications to use a VPN: Firefox, and maybe a podcatcher. I cannot, for the life of me, get any of the split tunneling tutorials to work for me. I installed Qomui, which won't load my VPN. I followed a tutorial where I create a new user called 'vpn' and run apps as that user, but the script threw an error and the applications wouldn't start.

I run OpenWRT and I'm open to setting up the VPN on the router itself, if this is going to be easier. But I'm going nuts trying to figure this out so if anyone has a good GUI, tutorial, script, or other solution, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: If you need vpn for a browser you can just install add-on from firefox addon-ons page

Comment: You can utilize iptables to route the traffic from a specific user to a different routing table like in the tutorial here:
https://gist.github.com/GAS85/4e40ece16ffa748e7138b9aa4c37ca52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I have the same goal : split tunnelling for my Ubuntu openvpn client.
From what I read so far, the network-manager (GUI) within Ubuntu-Gnome does not support such routing settings. It will route everything on the created network interface (tun0). This is a limitation from that software.
I did succeed doing that following these ways, instructions were provided by my VPN provider  :

1. Got the .conf file from my openvpn provider (not the .ovpn file).
2. Edit the file and add some routing commands (provided by the openvpn provider) such as "route-nopull ; route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 ; route W.X.Y.Z 255.255.255.255"
3. run the following command : sudo openvpn --config my-openvpn.conf (you may also make that automatic at boot time moving files to /etc/openvpn dir, although not yet tested).

Doing that, nothing is routed to the tun0 interface created, all trafic is still going to default enp3s0. Then I go to the App I want to use vpn, and add SOCKS5 proxy settings provided by my VPN provider. And then that App uses the tun0 network interface.

I hope this is of help.

Comment: Which credentials does opevpn provide socks5 proxy port to connect?